# Symfony entity changed and persisted by another process. My long-running process doesn't detect it

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine, multiprocessing

I have a long running symfony process that queries entities regularly using

```
 $msg = $this->entityManager->getRepository('App\Entity\Message')->findOneBy([
        'id' => $id
    ]);
```

I get the message and all is fine.Two minutes later the same message is changed and persisted by another Symfony process. Now 5 minutes later I again query the same msg Id:

```
 $msg = $this->entityManager->getRepository('App\Entity\Message')->findOneBy([
        'id' => $id
    ]);
```

Unfortunately 
I again get the original message, probably because it is cached, i.e. Symfony/Doctrine didn't detect that the other process had modified the database

I can of course do

```
$this->entityManager->refresh($msg);
```

, but that would cause a lot of unnecessary load on the database.

Is there a better way, e.g. setting a general timeToLive for the cache? Or even better: have Symfony detect when the cache gets "dirty"?

Comment: This is pretty much just the way Doctrine's unit of work is designed.  When an entity is loaded it stays loaded and any subsequent request for it returns the in memory version.  Normally, in a request/response environment, the unit of work starts fresh on each request.  For a long running process, not so much.  And there is really no way for Doctrine to know the database has changed without asking the database.  Something you seem to be trying to avoid.  If performance is really being impacted then you could add work around code.